# What should I see on an HDMI TV if I power on a RPi 3 Model B just with no SD card?

Tags: hardware, power

There are lot of questions and answers that tell about no-video involving booting process. What if I do not try to boot? Should I see something?

I think the biggest distributor in my country sold me an used and even broken card (now I can see some other signals on the card).

I am powering with micro USB. A red led is on. TV accepts HDMI as input (in other case, option is grey and can't be selected)

Comment: If you power the Raspberry Pi with no SD card and connect it to a display you will see nothing. This is because the OS is installed onto the SD card, which the Pi boots off. If there is no SD card there is no OS for the Pi to load, so it is not going to be able to output anything to the TV.

Comment: @DarthVader, that was obvious to me. But nevertheless I expected some **nice** signal of "something is running" on the board, just with power.  A new arduino has a flashing led, which at least involves some transistors working. To keep a red led on, a resistor is enough (and the rest can be bad).  I had to wait up to the night to use my new board, meanwhile I think I brought a brick.  Initial load was easy and straight, Good! but not relevant to the many hours of my 
anguish.  Thanks a Lot :)

Comment: to be presise I only disagree and dislike the fact that, "it is not going to be able to output anything to the TV".  I thought the board along should be able to show *something* on the screen, a flashing cursor, a raspberry o whatever that only a working micro can do

Answer (score 0):

Sorry perhaps I was precipitate. [Here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=58151) is the answer from oficial site

> No Video without Booting
>   In contrast to other computing systems
>   you might be used to using, the Raspberry Pi does not have any
>   built-in software (firmware). Notably, it doesn't have any form of
>   Basic Input/Output System (BIOS). All the software needed to run the
>   Pi must be loaded from the SD card. On a PC, the BIOS allows it to
>   generate a video signal immediately, even when you have no operating
>   system installed, and no storage device is connected. The Pi works
>   differently. Without access to its storage device it cannot load any
>   software at all, and then it does absolutely nothing! Your job is to
>   provide it with a completely up-to-date and correctly imaged SD card.
>   Using an SD card containing an obsolete version of the operating
>   system can cause some functions not to work, or worse.